# How to go back to a JFrames in Java

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I have a button in a JFrame, if pressed, it takes us to another frame. 
I used this code:

```
private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

    SecondForm secondform = new SecondForm();
    secondform.setVisible(true);
    setVisible(false);
    dispose();
    }
```

So the new frame opens and everything is ok. Then i placed another button -in the second frame- in order to go back to the previous frame. I used this code:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

    MainForm Mform = new MainForm();
    Mform.setVisible(true);
    setVisible(false);
    dispose();
}
```

The thing is, i don't think this is the right way to do this. What i want is to:

- hide the first frame
- show the new second one
- dispose the second one
- show again the first

Is there a way to do that using the first MainForm instance and not creating a new one every time i want to go back. 
I monitored my program and every time i go back and forth the frames and as i suspected, the ram being used by it keeps increasing.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT :** I have a login system and when the user put the correct credentials a new ManiForm instance is created.

```
MainForm Mform = new MainForm();
Mform.setVisible(true);
```

That is the instance i want to use. Ii there a way to make MForm visible again from the secondform?

First of all thanks for the help!

I agree that it is easier not to use more than one JFrames, but can you please tell me which is the better way to do what i asked in the first post?
The answer **Robin** gave me is very nice but i don't know what to put as an argument there*:

```
java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
    *   new SecondForm().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
```

It's from the auto-generated code from NetBeans.

I tried

```
new SecondForm(super).setVisible(true);
```

but i still get compile errors. Apparently i must put `super.something()` but i don't know what. I tried many but no luck.

Comment: How many professional applications do you use that swap windows willy-nilly? Not many I'll bet. Instead consider swapping *views* using a single JFrame and a CardLayout that swaps JPanels, each with a different view for your GUI.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels agreed. Or open a new dialog but at least leave the original main application window visible and active

Answer (score 9):

you shouldn't use more then one frame.

You should have NOTHING in JFrame except defaultExitOperation, size, preferedsize and visible true.
Instead place all buttons and fields into a JPanel and add/remove the JPanel from the JFrame.

If you want another Window open use JDialog.

btw: you can have your MainFrame setVisible false and open a JDialog with your MainFrame as parent. Only if someone writes down the right user + password you make the MainFrame visible.

Comment: +1 for a single frame in an application along with child dialogs.

Answer (score 3):

For swing applications, the standard is to use a STATIC MAIN FRAME, in other words, make your main frame (mframe) static and add methods to pop-up new frames, dialogs, optionPanes, etc. You can even control the visibility of the main frame throw static calls. That's the way you implement a UNIQUE FRAME for your application, even tho you instance other frames for navigation, all child frames can refer to the main frame without the need of passing it as parameter to constructors or creating new instances of it.

### The Main Class

`/* to start the application */

```
public class Main{
    public static MainFrame MFRAME;

    public static void main(String[] args){
        /*use this for thread safe*/
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Main.MFRAME = new MainFrame(/*init parms to constructor*/);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

`

### The Main Frame

`/* to create the main frame */

```
public class MainFrame extends JFrame{

    public MainFrame(/*your constructor parms*/){
        /* constructor implementation */
    }


    public void openOtherFrame(/*your parms*/){
        OtherFrame oFrm = new OtherFrame(/*your parms*/);
    }

    /* other methods implementation */
}
```

`

### The child frame

`/* to open child frames controling the visibility of the main frame*/

```
public class OtherFrame extends JFrame{

    public OtherFrame(/*your constructor parms*/){
        /* hide main frame and show this one*/
        Main.MFRAME.setVisible(false);
        this.setVilible(true);
        /* do something else */
        /* show main frame and dispose this one*/
        Main.MFRAME.setVisible(true);
        this.dispose();
    }

    /* other methods implementation */
}
```

`

Comment: this is also known as "Singleton" design pattern

Comment: but definitely _not_ what you are typically doing in a swing application ;-)

Comment: hi kleopatra, could you clarify "not typically doing in a swing app"? I would say that this is quite typical, or am I wrong in such statement?

Comment: Singletons are evil always :-) Don't know how you reached the _STANDARD_ - never seen it in any serious app (nor even the trivial tutorial examples which show many suboptimal thingies)

Comment: Ok, I agree with "singletons are evil" and it may not be widely used nor abused - the abuse on singletons turned them into evil. Maybe newbies have made misuse of singletons quite a lot so we have such understanding, but it is useful in very specific cases, and this one does not really create a big hole in common practices - of course a "Factory" pattern would be more elegant, but it does not make it wrong, right? ;)

Comment: thank you, +1 it was helpful and solved my situation.

Answer (score 1):

If you pass your `MainForm` to the `SecondForm` class (for example using a constructor parameter) the `SecondForm` instance can make the original `MainForm` instance visible again instead of creating a new one.

For example

```
public class SecondForm extends JFrame{
 private final MainForm mainForm;
 public SecondForm( MainForm form ){
   mainForm = form;
 }
 private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
  mainForm.setVisible(true);
  setVisible(false);
  dispose();
 }  
}
```

and in your `MainForm` class

```
private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
 SecondForm secondform = new SecondForm( this );
 secondform.setVisible(true);
 setVisible(false);
 dispose();
}
```

Comment: @user1136176 I added an example to my answer

Comment: I checked your post, and my answer still stands. Just pass the `MainForm` instance to the `SecondForm` class. And then start reading the other answers and comments to decide whether you actually would want to start swapping frames

Comment: Ok. I understand now. One last thing. I use NetBeans and it autogenerates some code. My answer is what do i put as an argument in SecondForm() there?                                                              
 `/* Create and display the form */
 java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

     public void run() {
  new SecondForm().setVisible(true);
     }
 });`